# PHP-скрипты не выполняются, а отдаются в виде текстовых файлов

Tags: php, хостинг

Купил хостинг на nic.ru, но никак не могу настроить. php-скрипты не выполняются, а отдаются в виде текстовых файлов. Кто нибудь сталкивался?

Comment: Потому что тариф «101» ;)

Comment: нифига :) 201

Comment: Тогда я не знаю в чём проблема.Напиши в тех. поддержку, если она там есть.

Comment: Топай на их форум и там тоже самое пиши и в поддержку ломись с криками "Уроды ИНТЕРПРЕТАТОР включите!" :DDDD

Comment: попробую )

Comment: Отдаются скрипты или результат их работы?

Comment: нет...весь код в текстовике я так понял :DDD

Answer (score 1):

В .htaccess добавьте

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .phtml
```

Comment: блин, тоже не прокатило

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй вот такую строку в .htaccess

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm .php
```

Comment: добавил, опять борода :(

Answer (score 0):

У вас на сервере отключен PHP.

Comment: включен... могу даже скрин прислать...

Comment: пришлите. посмотрим.

Comment: сделай index.php с phpinfo(); в корне, если уж не прокатит то действительно интерпретатор как то странно себя ведет

Comment: Ждем скрин, @boris - если нитерпретатор не обрабатывает php код, то будь то phpinfo, или еще что-либо это уже говорит о неработоспособности интерпретатора.

Comment: да, однозначно не пашет php

Answer (score 0):

Права на выполнение стоят? если нет, то chmod 755 <scriptname.php>